# JDBC error when querying Oracle 11.1 (ORA-00933)

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc, lazy-evaluation, ora-00933

I have searched high and low for answers so apologies if it has already been answered!

Using R I am trying to perform a lazy evaluation of Oracle 11.1 databases. I have used JDBC to facilitate the connection and I can confirm it works fine. I am also able to query tables using dbGetQuery, although the results are so large that I quickly run out of memory.

I have tried dbplyr/dplyr tbl(con, "ORACLE_TABLE") although I get the following error:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT *
FROM "ORACLE_TABLE" AS "zzz39"
WHERE (0 = 1) (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended)
```

I have also tried using  db_table <- tbl(con, in_schema('ORACLE_TABLE'))

This is happening with all databases I am connected to, despite being able to perform a regular dbGetQuery.

Full Code:

```
# Libraries
library(odbc)
library(DBI) 
library(config)
library(RJDBC) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(xlsx)
library(RSQLite)
library(dbplyr)
```

## Oracle Connection

```
db <- config::get('db')
drv1 <- JDBC(driverClass=db$driverClass, classPath=db$classPath)
con_db <- dbConnect(drv1, db$connStr, db$orauser, db$orapw,  trusted_connection = TRUE)

    # Query (This one works but the data set is too large)



 db_data <- dbSendQuery(con_db, "SELECT end_dte, reference, id_number FROM ORACLE_TABLE where end_dte > '01JAN2019'")

    **# Query (this one wont work)**



 oracle_table <- tbl(con_db, "ORACLE_TABLE")
```

Solved:

1. Updated Rstudio + Packages.
2. Follow this manual:
   https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connect-oracle-database-r-rjdbc-tianwei-zhang/
3. Insert the following code after 'con':

   sql_translate_env.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_translate_env.Oracle
   sql_select.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_select.Oracle
   sql_subquery.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_subquery.Oracle

Comment: Please include the full code related to the query which seems to be getting executed.

Comment: Valid point, I have now included the code.

Comment: So here's the thing: neither version really works, because the first runs out of memory and the second just fails.  I don't know the `tbl` function, but even if it worked, you would still run out of memory.  Maybe you should try to alter your query to return a smaller result set, and just use the first version.